# database transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, database

If I'm using a mysql client(eg. squirrel) to execute an update query, after 10 seconds, I cancelled the query, would there be partial update or would everything that's done be rolled back?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) on BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT, AND ROLLBACK.

I believe it is going to depend upon the engine you choose (e.g., InnoDB) and I saw the following comment about ROLLBACK:

> If you issue a ROLLBACK statement
>   after updating a nontransactional
>   table within a transaction, an
>   ER_WARNING_NOT_COMPLETE_ROLLBACK
>   warning occurs. Changes to
>   transaction-safe tables are rolled
>   back, but not changes to
>   nontransaction-safe tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is enclosed within a Transaction block, and if you stopped it in the middle, everything would be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

If MySql has any claims of being a real database it would roll everything back, even more so for a single update statement.